# Is there a way to force the browser to close <br> tags?

Tags: xml, html, xml-parsing, xhtml

If I look into the code source in any site the `<br>` tags aren't closed with another `</br>` tag. Is it possible to force the browser to use the closing tag ? 
Why isn't it closing anyway ?

The reason I'm asking this is because some xml parsers are throw errors when a tag isn't closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no closing br tag. It's a single tag representing a break. It doesn't enclose anything.

Only when writing XHTML (which is XML), you have to close each element, so then the tag is written as a self-closing tag: `<br/>`. I think theoretically you could write it as `<br></br>` too, as long as there is no content in it, but I've never seen it written like that.

XML is a strict standard, so it makes sense that XML parsers fail when encountering an unclosed `<br>` tag, and you should always write it as `<br/>` if your doctype is XHTML.

(plain) HTML is (was) based on SGML rather than XML and does allow unclosed tags. In HTML, including HTML5, you can write `<br>`.

Sometimes you still see `<br />` (often with a space) in normal HTML documents too. This is mainly because for a while it looked like XHTML was going to be the new standard and people wanted to be prepared. Most HTML parsers are quite forgiving and just ignore the `/` even when the doctype formally didn't allow it.

By now it's clear that HTML5 is the de facto standard, and there is no need at all to close or self-close `<br>` tags. But HTML5 is not XML and cannot be parsed with XML parsers. You should use an HTML parser.